# List nested array results from decoded json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am working with the riot api and I am trying to figure out how to list the results from the summoner api. Here is what I have so far:

```
//Start getting Summoner Name
$summjsonstring = 'https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/' . $name . '?api_key=' . $key;
//echo $summjsonstring;
$summjsonstringcontents = file_get_contents($summjsonstring);
echo $summjsonstringcontents;
echo "<p>";
$summnameresults = json_decode($summjsonstringcontents, true);
foreach($summnameresults as $data => $value)
   echo '<br/>'. $data.' : '. $value;
```

This seems to only return

```
testname : Array
```

Here is what the JSON looks like:

```
{"testname ":{"id":2354235,"name":"Test Name","profileIconId":691,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1410406459000}}
```

Comment: Have you tried checking if values are correct, using `print_r()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly what it is supposed to be ;) Your `$data` var holds a string, and can be printed as-is, but the `$value` var is an array, and cannot be printed just like that. However you can access it like any array, example given: `echo $value['id'];` will print out `2354235`.

Try this piece of code, it'll help you further:

```
//Start getting Summoner Name
$summjsonstring = 'https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/' . $name . '?api_key=' . $key;
//echo $summjsonstring;
$summjsonstringcontents = file_get_contents($summjsonstring);
echo $summjsonstringcontents;
echo "<p>";
$summnameresults = json_decode($summjsonstringcontents, true);
foreach($summnameresults as $data => $value)
   echo '<br/>'. $data.' : '. $value['name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want whats inside, you can access that level directly inside the foreach. Example:

```
foreach($summnameresults['testname '] as $data => $value) {
                       //  ^^ access the array directly 
    echo "$data => $value <br/>";
}
```

Note: I do not know if this is a typo on your json string .`testname`has a leading space

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($summnameresults as $key => $value) {
  echo $key;
  foreach($value as $k => $v) {
    echo '<br/>'.$k.' : '.$v;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To view the array structure use:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($summnameresults);
```

if you want to know their data types then use:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($summnameresults);
```